# Strings: Making Anagrams

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

**Problem Statement**

**Input Format**

The first line contains a single string, a. The second line contains a single string, b.

**Constraints**

1<= |a|,|b| <= 10^4

It is guaranteed that and consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters (i.e., through ). Output Format

Print a single integer denoting the number of characters you must delete to make the two strings anagrams of each other.

**Sample Input**

cde

abc

**Sample Output**

4

**Explanation**

We delete the following characters from our two strings to turn them into anagrams of each other:

Remove d and e from cde to get c. Remove a and b from abc to get c. We must delete characters to make both strings anagrams, so we print on a new line.

**Solution**

```
public class Solution {
public static int numberNeeded(String first, String second) {

    StringBuilder firstBuilder = new StringBuilder(first);
    StringBuilder secondBuilder = new StringBuilder(second);
    int numberNeeded = firstBuilder.length() + secondBuilder.length();

    for (int i=0; i<first.length(); i++) {

        char currentChar = first.charAt(i);

        for (int j=0; j<secondBuilder.length(); j++) {
            char charToCompare = secondBuilder.charAt(j);

            if (charToCompare == currentChar) {
                firstBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
                secondBuilder.deleteCharAt(j);
                numberNeeded -= 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return numberNeeded;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstArray = in.next();
    String secondArray = in.next();
    System.out.println(numberNeeded(firstArray, secondArray));
}
}
```

Can I please get feedback on my code and also on my solution approach? Also, can someone guide me about the time and space complexity of this solution? How do we calculate it and how can I make it better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get the feeling that this should be somehow accomplishable by an algorithm based on the Levenshtein-Distance computation...

Comment: @Vogel612 i'll have a look at this, I didn't know about this algorithm

Comment: @Vogel612 Levenshtein distance is a definite over-engineering here.

Comment: user vnp below is right. build a map for each string, and then sum up all the differences. 0(n+m)

Comment: The variable `firstBuilder` is redundant, because apart from `firstBuilder.length()`, its contents are never read, and the length can also be queried from the `String` `first`.

Comment: @Stingy firstBuilder contains the content of the first string and the contents get deleted. Since strings are immutable, therefore, i had to convert it into its equivalent stringbuilder obect to delete the characters

Comment: @a-ina Yes, I understand that, but the point I was trying to make is that there is no point in deleting characters from `firstBuilder` in the first place. The program would produce the exact same result if you left `firstBuilder` unchanged, since you never read its contents after you modify it.

Comment: @Stingy oh yes, you're right. I used another approach before coming up with this one and I think that's why I got a little confused. Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity is \$O(NM)\$ where \$N,M\$ are lengths of the strings. Surely is is too much. The solution can be reached in \$O(N+M)\$. In pseudocode:

```
    build a character histogram from the first string
    build a character histogram from the second string
    for each c in alphabet,
        result += max(hist1[c], hist2[c]) - min(hist1[c], hist2[c])
```

Comment: I like your approach. Since this was the second challenge in the hackerrank, therefore, I thought we were supposed to come up with a solution without using any other data structure like hash maps, vectors, etc.

Comment: @a-ina It only requires an array (well, two of them). But don't be afraid to use ADTs as you see fit. Hackerrank doesn't really care, as long as the solution passes.

Comment: @vpn thankyou. I'll keep this in mind